# How to get dramatiq to work with redis in a Windows / WSL environment?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dramatiq

I've created a simple script to test dramatiq with redis:

```
broker_redis = RedisBroker(host='localhost', port=6379)

@dramatiq.actor
def sq(x):
    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))
    return x * x
```

I'm using this command to run inside WSL (as prescribed by the docs):

```
dramatiq script_name:broker_redis
```

It runs without any errors, and it prints out these lines on the console:

```
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,535] [PID 508] [MainThread] [dramatiq.MainProcess] [INFO] Dramatiq '1.8.1' is booting up.
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,535] [PID 511] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(1)] [INFO] Worker process is ready for action.
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,546] [PID 510] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(0)] [INFO] Worker process is ready for action.
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,548] [PID 544] [MainThread] [dramatiq.ForkProcess(0)] [INFO] Fork process 'dramatiq.middleware.prometheus:_run_exposition_server' is ready for action.
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,559] [PID 513] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(3)] [INFO] Worker process is ready for action.
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,569] [PID 512] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(2)] [INFO] Worker process is ready for action.
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,581] [PID 515] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(5)] [INFO] Worker process is ready for action.
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,596] [PID 514] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(4)] [INFO] Worker process is ready for action.
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,634] [PID 516] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(6)] [INFO] Worker process is ready for action.
[2020-05-06 09:46:28,634] [PID 517] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(7)] [INFO] Worker process is ready for action.
```

But when I import this function in an interpreter and use `send` method on it...

```
from script_name import sq
sq.send(10)
```

...it waits for a few seconds and then raises a `dramatiq.errors.ConnectionClosed` error:

```
dramatiq.errors.ConnectionClosed: AMQPConnectionError: (AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'Unknown error'),)
```

It seems that this call is not able to send the message to dramatiq running inside WSL.

Note: I haven't installed RabbitMQ, but I assumed it's not required if I'm going to use Redis.

Comment: Do you have redis running? If you would be using RabbitMQ, it would be the same, you would need a RabbitMQ service running.